ytdl-core is returning a stream with nothing in it when I try to download a video
I am trying to use ytdl-core in an AWS lambda function to upload an .mp4 of a youtube video to an S3 bucket. However, I cannot get ytdl to create a stream with any data in it, so nothing is getting written to the s3 bucket.
Here is the snippet of code I am using to upload the video to the s3 bucket.
if (video_url.includes("youtube")){
    const passthrough = new PassThrough();
    const video_file = ytdl(video_url, { quality: '18' });
    const pipe_response = video_file.pipe(passthrough);
    console.log(pipe_response);
    const key_name = id.concat('.', 'mp4');
    const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: REGION });
    const upload = new Upload({
      client: s3Client,
      params: {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: key_name,
        Body: passthrough
      },
      partSize: 1024*1024*64,
      leavePartsOnError: false,
    });
    try {
      const response = await upload.done();
      console.log(response);
      console.log('Upload done');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error uploading video:', err);
    }
  }

I have tried modifying the ytdl call quite a bit to get it to work, such as adding an await, or changing the options but I can't seem to get anything to work. The streams always return:
PassThrough {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    state: 6160,
    highWaterMark: 524288,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,

Right now nothing is getting pushed to the buffer or the s3 bucket when the function is called.
Does ytdl-core even work right now? I see it has not been updated in a year. Is there a better library for nodejs that I could be using?

I don't think ytdl-core is working at the moment. Try use console to log a format then copy url and paste on browser to know if it'll play the video because i tried this and it's showing me a 403 error (Forbidden) instead. Maybe the url needs to be deciphered. Now i made use of a popular YouTube video downloader but it's working properly

On August 13, 2024, ytdl-core was officially depreciated by its maintainers. The recommendation is that you move to another package, such as @distube/ytdl-core, which works for most cases.

The package has been depreciated. Use this instead - distubejs/ytdl-core

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
